# How to fetch data through "has_many" associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations, has-many

I have the following structure of models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
end
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :colors
  has_many :favorities
end
```

It means that a company has many colors. Every user can favorite a company (and I can print out then every color that the respective company offers).

But I am trying to display all colors that companies I've favorited offers.

I've tried it something like this:

```
favorited_colors = current_user.favorites.colors

undefined method `colors' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Favorite:0x007fe037da01f0>
```

and

```
favorited_colors = current_user.favorites.companies.colors

undefined method `companies' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Favorite:0x007fe038ce8db0>
```

Is there any other way how to get a list of all colors from favorited companies than to iterated via **each** loops through all favorited companies and save all colors into an array?

Thank you

Comment: you don't have connection between neither user and company nor user and color. Therefor no, there is no way to get what you are trying

Answer (score 0):

This should work from rails 3.1 on:

```
class User
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :companies, :through => :favorites
  has_many :favorit_colors, :through => :companies
end
```

And then

```
favorited_colors = current_user.favorit_colors
```

This is not tested, though.

Answer (score 0):

**Collections**

The problem you have is that you're calling the `companies` method on a collection object

The issue here is that you can only call methods on single instances of objects. This is demonstrated quite well with the error you're seeing:

```
undefined method `companies' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Favorite:0x007fe038ce8db0>
```

The way you *should* attempt to get this to work is to call the following:

```
current_user.favorites.each do |favourite|
    = favourite.colors
end
```

I understand what you're looking to achieve, so let me give you some ideas:

---

**Association Extensions**

There's a functionality of Rails called [ActiveRecord Association Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions), which could give you the ability to provide what you're seeking:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :favorites do
      def colors
         # Business logic for colours here
      end
   end
end
```

Now this is totally untested. However, I have experience with this deep part of Rails, and I therefore know that you'll have the following data-sets to work with:

> - `proxy_association.owner` returns the object that the association is a part of.
> - `proxy_association.reflection` returns the reflection object that describes the association.
> - `proxy_association.target` returns the associated object for belongs_to or has_one, or the collection of associated objects for
>     has_many or has_and_belongs_to_many.

From this, you'll be able to construct an array / object based off the `colors` you wish to show:

```
has_many :favorites do
  def colors #totally untested
    colors = {}
    favorites = proxy_association.target 

    favorites.each do |favorite|
       favorite.company.colors.each do |color|
         colors << color
       end
    end

    return colors
  end
end
```